# I have several .KMZ files that open in google earth. I need to load these files into java. I use Eclipse is there a way?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-earth, kmz

I assume that there is some sort of google api for this. I just have no idea where to find it any help?

Answer (score 0):

The .kmz is just a standard zipfile -- unzip it, and one or more KML (xml) files will be inside.